# Issues with getline/file reading in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, file-io, unicode, getline

I created some .txt files on my Mac (didn't think that would matter at first, but...) so that I could read them in the application I am making in (unfortunately) Visual Studio on a different computer. They are basically files filled with records, with the number of entries per row at the top, e.g.:

```
2
int int 
age name
9 Bob
34 Mary
12 Jim
...
```

In the code, which I originally just made (and tested successfully) on the Mac, I attempt to read this file and similar ones:

```
Table TableFromFile(string _filename){ //For a database system

  ifstream infile; 
  infile.open(_filename.c_str()); 

  if(!infile){
    cerr << "File " << _filename << " could not be opened."; 
    exit(1); 
  }

  //Determine number attributes (columns) in table, 
  //which is number on first line of input file 
  std::string num;
  getline(infile, num); 
  int numEntries = atoi(num.c_str()); 
  ...
  ...
```

In short, this causes a crash! As I looked into it, I found some interesting "Error reading characters of string" issues and found that `numEntries` is getting some crazy negative garbage value. This seems to be caused by the fact that "num", which should just be "2" as read from the first line, is actually coming out as "ÿþ2".

From a little research, it seems that these strange characters are formatting things...perhaps unicode/Mac specific? In any case, they are a problem, and I am wondering if there is a fast and easy way to make the text files I created on my Mac cooperate and behave in Windows just like they did in the Mac terminal. I tried connecting to a UNIX machine, putting a txt file there, running unix2dos on it, and put into back in VS, but to no avail...still those symbols at the start of the line! Should I just make my input files all over again in Windows? I am very surprised to learn that what you see is not always what you get when it comes to characters in a file across platforms...but a good lesson, I suppose.

Comment: The bytes at the beginning of the file are a Unicode [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), indicating that the text file is encoded in UTF-16 (LE). How did you create the text file? With a text editor? Do you need Unicode capabilities in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter indicated, the bytes you're seeing are the byte order mark. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

"ÿþ" is 0xFFFE, the UTF-16 "little endian" byte order mark. The "2" is your first actual character (for UTF-16, characters below 256 will be represented by bytes of the for 0xnn00;, where "nn" is the usual ASCII or UTF-8 code for that character, so something trying to read the bytes as ASCII or UTF-8 will do OK until it reaches the first null byte).

If you need to puzzle out the Unicode details of a text file the best tool I know of is the free SC Unipad editor (www.unipad.org). It is Windows-only but can read and write pretty much any encoding and will be able to tell you what there is to know about the file. It is very good at guessing the encoding.

Unipad will be able to open the file and let you save it in whatever encoding you want: ASCII, UTF-8, etc.